# How to identify IFrame dynamically in selenium using Java

Tags: html, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate my application and in my application IFrame id and name is changing dynamically, I am not able to uniquely Identify my Iframe. This is my HTML [Ifrmae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXMli.png) .In this Iframe name is changing dynamically, currently, the IFrame name is "tvcTabs0_c340contentFrame" and in this name, numbers are changed dynamically, I tried it with ID Name, Source, contains,starts-with keyword but I am not able to make uniquely.Next Iframe is tvcTabs0_c341contentFrame, and I have to go under Iframe 1 inside that nested IFrame is present.

Please let me know how to dynamically identify it ..I tried it with indexing also but it is not working.

Comment: Can you please paste your html code here, someone might be able to figure out something for you

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. Mock up the HTML of the different `IFRAME`s on the page. Edit your question and put all this info in there.

Answer (score 0):

We can handle iFrames in following 3 ways.

By Index

By Name or Id

By Web Element

In your case ID's and WebElement properties are dynamic, you can use index of that particular iFrame.
iFrame index starts with 0.

For example, if you have 4 iFrames in the web page and you want to switch to 3rd iFrame then snippet will be like below.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(2);
```

Comment: yes that I have tried ,driver.switchTo().frame(0).switchTo().frame("tableContentFrame").switchTo().frame("tableBodyRight"); Still not able to traverse

Comment: In under Iframe "tableBodyRight" (last Iframe)I have to click on one link.But this is not working in my case. I am getting error like I am not able to find tableContentFrame

Comment: You said id's and class names are dynamic then why you're providing 'tableBodyRight' to switch to that element. After driver.switchTo().frame(0); write separate line of code to perform action on other element. Do not clb like driver.switchTo().frame(2).switchTo().frame('XXX').switchTo()....etc.it won't work like that.

Comment: tableBodyRight is child Iframe, Parent Iframe name is changing dynamically .and I have already tried without clubbing them and for other Iframe when I clubbed then it is working fine.

Comment: If child has static values and it is table then why don't you use webElement tag for childs iframe instead of id  and class. driver.switchTo.frame(0).switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("tr"))).switchTo.....etc like this.

Comment: Child is also IFrame

Comment: Yes. For child use web element instead of id or class